# unexpected behavior of scanf() and gets()

Tags: c, file, scanf, gets

I want to write a line ( including spaces ) to the file in one go with following code:-

```
//in main
char ch[40];
FILE *p;
char choice;
p=fopen("textfile.txt","w");
printf("%s\n","you are going to write in the first file" );
while (1)
{
    gets(ch);// if i use scanf() here the result is same,i.e,frustrating
    fputs(ch,p);
    printf("%s\n","do you want to write more" );
    choice=getche();
    if (choice=='n'|| choice=='N')
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Result of above code is frustrating to me and is hard to explain.but still i will try.
If i enter,say,

```
"my name is bayant."
```

and press enter the statment comes to screen is

```
"do you want to write more"
```

it is good till now,but when i prees a key other than 'n' or 'N' (as required by the logic of program to write more line) then the message

```
"do you want to write more"
```

prints again.Now if i press other key than 'n' or 'N' the same line prints on screen.this procedure is followed and prints the statement

```
"do you want to write more"
```

4 times,which is the number of words,i.e, 4 in this case.By following this inflexible procedure i get the desired line on my file but if in response to first time printing of statement

```
"do you want to write more"
```

i press 'n' or 'N' then only first word ,i.e, "my" in this case prints on file.
so what is the solution to write a complete line on the file in one go?and why gets() and fputs() seems ineffective in this case?
thanxxx in advance.

Comment: Hopefully `gets()` was deprecated since C11

Comment: gets() buffer overflow heaven!!, please don't use gets, use fgets instead. on windows use gets_s()

Comment: @tesseract i know it but even i use scanf() the problem persists.

Comment: you haven't allocated space for the string. you haven't made the pointer point to valid memory

Comment: `char *ch;` should be `char ch[somenumber]`

Comment: @tesseract what is the solution to write a complete line ( including spaces ) to the file?

Comment: @Bayant_singh as SakthiKumar said, make it an array.

Comment: now i have changed it but still is not working.

Comment: what if you want to write 'n' to the file? may better check for empty line as NO; also you should ask first and then print, otherwise you might end up consuming the first character of the input line

Comment: @Manu343726 `gets()` wasn't deprecated in C11, it was outright *removed*. It doesn't appear in the standard *at all* except foot notes and the official note it was removed from the `stdio.h` header file. Its gone (*finally*).

Comment: @WhozCraig oh, thats faaar better, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this, its a very crude program but should give you an idea

your mistakes, you had only made a pointer to a char in your program, you need to allocate memory for the pointer using malloc, or the other option is just to make an array of chars. which I have done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){

char ch[100];
FILE *p;
char choice;
p=fopen("textfile.txt","w");
printf("%s\n","you are going to write in the first file" );
while (1)
{
// gets(ch);// if i use scanf() here the result is same,i.e,frustrating
int c =0;

fgets(ch,100,stdin);
fputs(ch,p);
printf("%s\n","do you want to write more" );
choice=getchar();
if (choice=='n'|| choice=='N')
    {
    break;
    }
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
return 0;
}
```

you program was repeating the `printf("%s\n","do you want to write more" );` because the input buffer had a \n written to it, you need to clear the buffer before reading. this line removes the newline from buffer `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

check this
[scanf() leaves the new line char in buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer)

Comment: Any particular reason for using `unsigned int c =0;` instead of `int c = 0;`?

Comment: I suspect `unsigned int c` will work too.  The `c != EOF` will cast the EOF to `unsigned` and will perform as expected.  Not that I recommend `unsigned int c`, just thought it was novel.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
scanf("%s",ch);
```

(Which I assume is what you mean by "scanf"), this will read one string. If you type

> "my name is bayant."

This will result in 4 strings: "my", "name", "is" and "bayant.".

Notice that, from your description, you don't want to read strings, you want to read *lines*. To read a whole line of text with scanf, you could use:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", ch);
scanf("%*c");
```

Which means:
Line 1: "read everything until you find a \n character".

Line 2: "read and ignore that '\n' character (which was left in the buffer)".

I should say that this is not a secure solution, as the user can easily overflow the "ch" buffer, but I'm sure you can find better ways to do that if this is a real concern in your particular case.

Comment: If one uses `scanf()`, suggest `if (1 == scanf("%39[^\n]%*c", ch)) Success();`